# Spring REST service hangs up when forwarding a ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am facing a problem using a REST service made up with Spring Boot 1.5. I am developing a REST service that acts as a proxy, forwarding requests to another REST service that exposes the same API.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class ProxyUserController {

    // Some initialization code

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        return restTemplate.postForEntity(userUrl, user, String.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class RestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate(UserErrorHandler errorHandler) {
            return new RestTemplateBuilder().errorHandler(errorHandler).build();
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class UserErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
        @Override
        public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
            // Empty body
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, to avoid that `RestTemplate` surrounds any error response with an exception that causes the creation of a new response with status `500`, I defined a customer `ResponseErrorHandler`.

The problem I faced is that if the `postForEntity` returns a response with an HTTP Status different from `200`, the response will never arrive at the caller, that hangs up until the timeout hits him.

However, if I create a new response starting from the one returned by the `postForEntity`, all starts to work smoothly.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> add(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    final ResponseEntity<?> response = 
        restTemplate.postForEntity(userUrl, user, String.class);
    return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatusCode()).body(response.getBody());
}
```

What the hell is going on? Why I can't reuse a `ResponseEntity` coming from another call?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Does your problem has solved???

Comment: @riccardo.cardin could you answer, does your problem has solved??

Comment: @Mateusz, I solved the problem ad I described in the last code snippet in my question. If I remember right, the problem was that part of an HTTP response, the payload, is a stream, and so cannot reuse it.